# Bash Script to Get Operating System + Version as string

Tags: bash

I want to make a bash script to take the system os and the version as a simple string.

Possible ways to get these info is from

- /etc/issue
- cat /etc/*-release
- lsb_release -a

and probably some others which i dont know. The problem is that i want the bash script to work on Ubuntu 12,13,14 and CentOS. Some of the above does not work in these systems. For example the lsb_release does not work on CentOS and sometimes the /etc/issue is empty so i'm little confused about it.

As for the string i want to get it in this way (and save it to var). I will give examples.

> If OS is Ubuntu **12.x** i want to take it as **ubuntu12**
>
> If OS is Ubuntu **13.x** i want to take it as **ubuntu13**
>
> If OS is CentOS **7.x** i want to take it as **centos7**

Is that easy?

THANK YOU

Comment: i think it's better to ask this in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: well i wasnt sure where to put it since it's the bash script actually and not the way to get the system os

Comment: did you try uname -a + some string manipulation?

Comment: No, that does not even output the distro name. At least in my VPS. Well i found out that the cat /etc/*-release actualyl works in all distros. The problem is the string now.

Comment: So, what bash script did you try? How does it not work? This is not a scripting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bash solution.  I tested on Ubuntu, but not on CentOS (I only have RHEL available now). But you can test the CentOS part and modify as needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

RELEASE=unknown

version=$( lsb_release -r | grep -oP "[0-9]+" | head -1 )
if lsb_release -d | grep -q "CentOS"; then
    RELEASE=centos$version
elif lsb_release -d | grep -q "Ubuntu"; then
    RELEASE=ubuntu$version
fi

echo $RELEASE
```

Or, without `lsb_release` on CentOS:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

RELEASE=unknown

if [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]; then
    version=$( cat /etc/redhat-release | grep -oP "[0-9]+" | head -1 )
    RELEASE=centos$version
elif [ -n $(which lsb_release 2> /dev/null) ] && lsb_release -d | grep -q "Ubuntu"; then
    version=$( lsb_release -d | grep -oP "[0-9]+" | head -1 )
    RELEASE=ubuntu$version
fi

echo $RELEASE
```

In any case, there's more than one way to skin this cat.